# Error with ridge regression in r survival package

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

I'm trying to use the survival package in R on a large dataset. When I try to enter lots of variables into the ridge function, I get an error. Strangely enough, this depends on the lengths of the variable names, but even with very short variable names (i.e. X1..X200), I can't have more than about 100 variables entered until I get this strange error message:

> Error in if (any(ord > 1)) stop("Penalty terms cannot be in an interaction") : 
>    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Here is an code example which will generate this error:

```
library(survival)

# Create a test data frame with random data (200 predictors)
test.data <-data.frame(outcome=rbinom(1000,1,0.1),
                       time=runif(1000,0,1000),replicate(200,rnorm(1000)))

# Create a string with ridge regression formula for 100 predictors
ridge.formula.100 <- paste0("Surv(time,outcome) ~ ridge(",
                            paste(paste0("X",1:100),collapse=","),",theta=1)")

# Run ridge regression with 100 predictors
m1 <- coxph(as.formula(ridge.formula.100),data=test.data)
summary(m1) # Yay it works!

# Create a string with ridge regression formula for 200 predictors
ridge.formula.120 <- paste0("Surv(time,outcome) ~ ridge(",
                            paste(paste0("X",1:120),collapse=","),",theta=1)")

# Run ridge regression with 120 predictors
m2 <- coxph(as.formula(ridge.formula.120),data=test.data) # Gives error
# Fails with error above
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong? Importantly, if the variable names are longer, even fewer variables can be entered into the ridge.

Thanks much!

Comment: Sounds like there is an upper limit on the number of characters that some formula-related function can handle. I do find myself wondering whether such models can be interpreted,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting all the variables into a matrix `allvars <- as.matrix(test.data[,3:ncol(test.data)])` then use this in your formula `ridge.formula <- as.formula(paste("Surv(time,outcome) ~ ridge(allvars,theta=1)"))`. Now the call `m2 = coxph(ridge.formula,data=test.data)`does not give that error.

Comment: Thanks! Any sense as to why this happens?